# How to write regex to find string below some particular character who is inside brackets in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am creating one regex to find data below some character.and from that `data` i found after some character i am separating data where i found colon. and getting right side of that. 
Below is my $string and my $regex.

```
In respect of Shareholders

Name:                                    xyx

Residential address:                     dublin

No of Shares:                            2

Name:                                    abc

Residential address:                     canada

No of Shares:                            2
```

Below is my $regex:

```
if (preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A)|In respect of Shareholders)\s*[^:\r\n]+:\h*\K.*~', $string, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

I am getting data in array:

`Array ( [0] => xyx [1] => dublin [2] => 2 [3] => abc [4] => canada [5] => 2 )`

My above regex is in working condition. But If I have something like this:

```
(In respect of Shareholders)

Name:                                    xyx

Residential address:                     dublin
```

Brackets within my charater. then my regex is not working.How to write regex for this kind of string.

Comment: Just escape the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

If that pattern holds true then it looks like you could get away with just this:

```
$string = '(In respect of Shareholders)

Name:                                    xyx

Residential address:                     dublin';

$string = $string . ' '; //Add a space to end of string so we capture the last value.

$string = preg_replace('/\s{1,}/', ' ', $string); //Take out unwanted spaces.

if (preg_match_all('/:\s(.*?)\s/', $string, $matches)) { //Just looking from the `:` for whats in between a single space.
print_r($matches[1]); //Index 1 contains just the group and not the full match.
}
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => xyx
    [1] => dublin
)
```

Hope that helps.